# How to initialize this struct values correctly?

Tags: c++, struct

I am kinda struggling to initialize structures correctly unfortunately and I am fairly new to using these here. How can I correctly initialize this struct and pass it into the function shown in the code below:

```
static const int nx = 128;
static const int ny = 128;
static const int ncomp = 2;

typedef struct r2cfft_t
{
    std::size_t nx, ny;
    fftw_plan plan;
    double *buffer_in;
    fftw_complex *buffer_out;
}r2cfft_t;
int r2cfft_initialize(r2cfft_t *const ctx, const std::size_t nx, const std::size_t ny);
int main(){ 

//init struct here and pass to r2cfft_initialize function
}
int r2cfft_initialize(r2cfft_t *const ctx, const std::size_t nx, const std::size_t ny)
{
    memset(ctx, 42, sizeof(r2cfft_t));
    if (!((ctx->nx = nx) && (ctx->ny = ny)))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ctx->buffer_in = fftw_alloc_real(nx * ny);
    if (!ctx->buffer_in)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ctx->buffer_out = fftw_alloc_complex(nx * nyk);
    if (!ctx->buffer_out)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ctx->plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(nx, ny, ctx->buffer_in, ctx->buffer_out, FFTW_PATIENT);
    if (!ctx->plan)
    {
        fftw_free(ctx->buffer_in);
        fftw_free(ctx->buffer_out);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what are the expected and observed behaviour.

Comment: Because with that piece of code we could rant for days without finding a solution to your problem.

Comment: This function will initialize the struct for you, I believe? Just `r2cfft_t x;`, then pass `&x` to the function?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks! I was testing this code and didn't understand how it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters.  Instead of this:

```
memset(ctx, 42, sizeof(r2cfft_t));
```

This:

```
*ctx = {};
```

Then your main is simply:

```
int main(){ 
    r2cfft_t ctx = {};
    size_t nx = 10; // put your value here
    size_t ny = 20; // put your value here
    if (r2cfft_initialize(&ctx, nx, ny)) {
       // success    
    }
    else {
       // error
    }
   
}
```

Cleaning up your code appropriately:

```
int r2cfft_initialize(r2cfft_t *const ctx, const std::size_t nx, const std::size_t ny)
{
    double* bufferIn = nullptr;
    fftw_complex* bufferOut = nullptr;
    int result = 0;
    
    if (ctx) {
        *ctx = {};

        if (nx > 0 && ny > 0) {
            bufferIn = fftw_alloc_real(nx * ny);
            bufferOut = fftw_alloc_complex(nx * ny);
            if (bufferIn && bufferOut) {
                auto plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(nx, ny, ctx->buffer_in, ctx->buffer_out, FFTW_PATIENT);
                if (plan) {
                    ctx->plan = plan;
                    ctx->nx = nx;
                    ctx->ny = ny;
                    ctx->buffer_in = bufferIn;
                    ctx->buffer_out = bufferOut;
                    result = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // cleanup on error
    if (!result) {
        fftw_free(bufferIn);
        fftw_free(bufferOut);
        *ctx = {};
    }
    return result;

}
```